# Converting multiple objects from string to numeric in one line r?

Tags: r, string, numeric

I have 3 strings with numbers.

```
a = "1"
b = "2"
c = "3"
```

The complicated way of converting `a`, `b` and `c` to numbers with `as.numeric()` is:

```
a = as.numeric(a)
b = as.numeric(b)
c = as.numeric(c)
```

How can I do this in one line?

A bit like this (obviously this doesn't work)

```
a,b,c = as.numeric(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `%=%` operator from `collapse`, it is possible

```
library(collapse)
c('a', 'b', 'c') %=% as.numeric(c(a, b, c))
```

-output

```
> a
[1] 1
> b
[1] 2
> c
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

a = "1"
b = "2"
c = "3"

map_int(c(a, b, c), as.integer)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, although a bit longer than the others:

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(c("a","b"), function(x){as.numeric(get(x))}), c("a","b")),.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your objects in a list, and then use `list2env`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
a = "1"
b = "2"
c = "3"

map(lst(a, b, c), as.numeric) %>% 
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using `type.convert` and `base R`:

```
list2env(type.convert(list(a = a, b = b, c = c), as.is = T), .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using `purrr::iwalk` and `assign`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iwalk(lst(a,b,c), ~ assign(.y, as.numeric(.x), envir = .GlobalEnv))
```